# Procedurally generated satellite view textures for large landmass rendering

Tags: textures, procedural-generation, terrain-rendering

I'm rendering a big land mass to be viewed from high altitude (40+ km), so I need satellite view style textures to be generated on the fly. The per vertex attributes I've got are:

- Biome (forest, snow, desert, mountain, etc)
- Elevation
- Moisture
- Temperature

Question is, is this even possible by solely shader code without any textures to sample from? It's downright impossible to find a decent looking texture pack for satellite view style textures. So far all techniques I've found were based on generating textures on existing terrain data, what I need is a procedural way to generate those on the fly per arbitrary terrain.

This is more or less the looks I'm aiming to achieve with already generated mesh and more biomes(tundra, desert, bare, shrubland, etc) and perhaps more "zoomed in":

[image]

Comment: You might want *small* textures to sample from so your forests look like trees, and so on. But you don't actual need them if you have a proc gen way of determining pixel color.

Comment: Can you give examples of what kind of look you want to achieve?

Comment: Something along the lines of the look of this: https://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?t=10768. Perhaps more zoomed in and with more biomes (snow, desert, tundra, bare, scorched), but more or less like that. https://www.cartographersguild.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=25888&d=1276558241

Comment: @Draco18s: This question is actually to find such a generic way of determining pixel color, based on pre-generated attributes, like biome type, elevation, moisture, temperature, etc :)

Comment: @user1617735 Yes, it is. The problem is that *texture is complicated* and those rules might be easier to encode in a small sample texture (hell, Minecraft encodes *lighting* as a texture and it's only got 256 possibilities). I've done some proc-gen texture work before and it's tough and I was working on *starscapes.* Getting something to look like "forest" instead of "grassland" involves noise. Anyway, that's why I only left a comment.

Comment: @Draco18s Noise is inavoidable in any case, to achieve something that doesn't look repeating. In any case, I've found this article https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00606769/document which describes techniques of rendering terrain based on real geographic data, giving exact formulas to be able to render per pixel. Problem is, it relies on all kinds of real world data I don't have. In any case, I suppose what you've meant is I'll still have to have small textures per biome to sample from?

Comment: @user1617735 Essentially yes. Instead of pulling from geographic data, you'd pull from a precomputed texture.  There isn't really a "take rainfall in cm/month, multiply by V, add temperature times Y, cube-root, and voila, color" formula.  Instead, you're going to have some sort of lookup table and textures *are* loopup tables and are easy to visualize, edit, and interpolate between values.

Answer (score 1):

This looks remarkably similar to [amitp's polygon map generator](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/), which produces islands like this:

[image: amitp island]

This was generated from scratch, no textures required. But as you'll find out in the article, he uses a variety of different techniques to get all the features in there: land formation, biome generation, placement of water features, noise filter. This won't be possible using pure shader code.

Comment: I've used some ideas to creating the terrain itself from Amit's post. Unfortunatelly he's not using WebGL to render, which is a shame. So basically what you're saying I still need textures to sample from?

Comment: Actually, I'm note sure it's entirely impossible on pixel shader level. Since I don't need details like trees, dunes, etc, I just need a way of slightly changing pixel color, predefined for each biomes by little bit, based on elevation, moisture, temperature, etc.